# counting smth in betweeen 1 month of register in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to count some data in a month after a specific date.
the table looks like this

| date | user_id | tx_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-08 | 123 | 1 |
| 2022-07-08 | 124 | 2 |
| 2022-07-10 | 123 | 3 |

I want to count every tx_id that user_id number 123 made in the a month from it's first tx_id. like how many tx_id s does user 123 made from 2022-07-08 to 2022-08-08?

I couldn't find any thing that can handle both finding if it's first tx_id and counting the other tx_ids one month from that date.

Comment: Question not clear ! Could you please edit your question and add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: Please read [How to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask your question in a way people can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general solution: Use `NOT EXISTS` to only get the first  month's orders per user. Then count found rows per user.

```
select user_id, count(*)
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select null
  from mytable older
  where older.user_id = mytable.user_id
  and older.date < mytable.date - interval 1 month
)
group by user_id
order by user_id;
```

Here is the same with getting the first date per user and using `<=`:

```
select user_id, count(*)
from mytable
where date <=
(
  select min(date) + interval 1 month
  from mytable first_month
  where first_month.user_id = mytable.user_id
)
group by user_id
order by user_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about grouping by user_id? Then count?
Count the number of transactions made by each user in the first month of their transaction.

```
SELECT t.user_id, COUNT(t.tx_id) AS tx_count FROM transactions t JOIN first_tx f ON t.user_id = f.user_id WHERE t.tx_date BETWEEN f.first_tx_date AND f.first_tx_date + INTERVAL ‘1 MONTH’ GROUP BY t.user_id;
```

eg

| user_id | tx_count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 10 |

Answer (score 1):

use this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS transaction_count
FROM your_table
WHERE user_id = 123
AND tx_id IN (
    SELECT tx_id
    FROM your_table
    WHERE user_id = 123
    ORDER BY date ASC
    LIMIT 1
)
AND date >= (
    SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM your_table
    WHERE user_id = 123
)
AND date <= (
    SELECT DATE_ADD(MIN(date), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    FROM your_table
    WHERE user_id = 123
);
```

here is the optimized query without subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS transaction_count
FROM your_table
WHERE user_id = 123
AND date >= (
    SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM your_table
    WHERE user_id = 123
)
AND date <= DATE_ADD(
    (
        SELECT MIN(date)
        FROM your_table
        WHERE user_id = 123
    ),
    INTERVAL 1 MONTH
);
```

Comment: *here is the optimized query without subquery:* and what is `date >= (
    SELECT MIN(date)
    FROM your_table
    WHERE user_id = 123` or `date <= DATE_ADD(
    (
        SELECT MIN(date)
        FROM your_table
        WHERE user_id = 123
    ),` aren't those subqueries ?